# Неправильный импорт из csv в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Здравствуйте. У меня имеется такой php код, который заливает данные из csv файла в базу MySQL

```
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r'); 
   while(!feof($file))
       {
    $mass = fgetcsv($file, 1700, ';');
    $j = count($mass);
    if($j > 1){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test (id, name_group, name, price, remainder, description) VALUES ('{$mass[0]}', '{$mass[1]}', '{$mass[2]}', '{$mass[3]}', '{$mass[4]}', '{$mass[5]}')");
              }
       }
    fclose($file);
    $mysqli->close();
```

Все отрабатывает, но в поле name_group у меня данные вида `Группа\Подгруппа` и когда заливатеся в базу получается `ГруппаПодгруппа` как можно не потерять этот слэш?
Если я прямо в php коде вывожу данные, это поле он мне показывает правильно.

Comment: Используйте или подготовленные выражения в запросе, чтобы передать переменные отдельно, или функцию real_escape_string() http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php чтобы данные проходили в базу безопасно.

Comment: Ну лежит же файл локально, выполни просто LOAD DATA INFILE, зачем всё через скрипт-то гнать?

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE на хостинге закрыт

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию PHP [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Суть функции как раз в решении подобных проблем, но ко всему прочему она призвана делать вставку данных в БД безопасной для самой БД.

Ваша вставка будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test (id, name_group, name, price, remainder, description)
VALUES (
'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[0])."',
'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[1])."',
'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[2])."',
'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[3])."',
'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[4])."',
'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[5])."'
)");
```

И ничего не потеряется, в БД попадет именно то, что вы туда хотите поместить

Comment: А теперь идите куда я автора послал в своем комментарии и посмотрите каков синтаксис функции.

Comment: по ссылке Visman, я добавил перед запросом код 
'$mass[1] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($mass[1]);' и все получилось, спасибо.

А при вставке кода выше, данные не записывались в базу.

Comment: Поправил код в ответе, привычка с `mysql_real_escape_string()` осталась )

Comment: спасибо, с поправленным кодом тоже все запускается и импортируется нормально

Comment: Валерий, если ответ подошел, пометьте как отвеченный ваш вопрос